# UITextField border specify radius in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextfield, border, radius

For some reason my corner radius that I want specified `30` will not display in my mainstoryboard for `Xcode` coding in `Swift`.

The textfield will appear if I use   `passWordTextField.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.roundedRect` (this will not allow me to specify a corner `radius/borderstyle` value), but will not if I use   `passWordTextField.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.init(rawValue: 30)!`.

```
func customTextField (xco: CGFloat, yco: CGFloat, widthLength: CGFloat, heightLength: CGFloat, printSize: CGFloat) {

    let passWordTextField =  UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: xco, y: yco, width: widthLength, height: heightLength ))
    let fontSize = CGFloat (printSize)
    passWordTextField.placeholder = "Enter text here" //set placeholder text
    passWordTextField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize) // set font size of text field

    //passWordTextField.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.init(rawValue: 30)!
    passWordTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 30.0
   // passWordTextField.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.roundedRect
    passWordTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
    passWordTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
    passWordTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
    passWordTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextField.ViewMode.whileEditing
    passWordTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControl.ContentVerticalAlignment.center
    passWordTextField.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate
    self.view.addSubview(passWordTextField)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see your changes on a Storyboard as well you can use a custom textfield class.

```
public class CustomTextField: UITextField {
    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
      super.init(frame: frame)
      prepare()
    }

    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
      super.init(coder: decoder)
      prepare()

    private func prepare() {
       layer.cornerRadius = 30
    }
}
```

Now on your Storyboard you are able to change the class of your textfield in the Identity inspector to your CustomTextField.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `@IBDesignable` and  `prepareForInterfaceBuilder()` to reflect your textField in the Interface Builder. Here are the steps:
1. make a subclass of `UITextField` like below

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable
class CostumTxtField: UITextField {
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        makeCorenerRadius()
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        makeCorenerRadius()

    }


 override init(frame: CGRect) {
      super.init(frame: frame)

    autocorrectionType = .no
    keyboardType = .default
    returnKeyType = .done
    clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
    contentVerticalAlignment = .center
    makeCorenerRadius()

    }

    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
      super.init(coder: decoder)

    func makeCorenerRadius(){
        backgroundColor = .white
        layer.cornerRadius = 20

}
}
```

2. In your view controller edit your function like follows:

```
func customTextField (xco: CGFloat, yco: CGFloat, widthLength: CGFloat, heightLength: CGFloat, fontSize: CGFloat) {

    let passWordTextField =  UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: xco, y: yco, width: widthLength, height: heightLength )) {

    passWordTextField.placeholder = "Enter text here" //set placeholder text
    passWordTextField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize) // set font size of text field

    passWordTextField.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate
    self.view.addSubview(passWordTextField)
}
```